# WPF,C# Get Response xml to Object

Tags: xml, wpf

I can Json  DeserializeObject, use 'Newtonsoft.json'

this

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url); 
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    /// Add Nuget 'Newtonsoft.json'
    /// Json DeserializeObject
    try
    {
        weathers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherModel>(json);
        weatherList.Add(weathers);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ": error");
    }
}
```

But I can't response Xml Data to DeserializeObject

I try to

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url); 
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    StreamReader xmlReader = new StreamReader(json); // Can't...  Error

    try
    {
        weathers = ???; // How to DeserializeObject ??
        weatherList.Add(weathers);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ": error");
    }

}
return weathers;
```

Is there a Nuget I can use, or is there a way to use the responsed xml for DeserializeObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XmlSerializer`.

```
string xmlData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WeatherModel));
    try
    {
        weathers = (WeatherModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
        weatherList.Add(weathers);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ": error");
    }
}
```

Comment: StreamReader xmlReader = new StreamReader(json) <- Error Invalid character in path

Comment: Use `StringReader`. Corrected the answer.

Comment: weathers = (WeatherModel)serializer.Deserialize(reader ); <- Error 
Xml (2,2) Error ...
----------------------------------
reader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<response><header><resultCode>00</resultCode><resultMsg>NORMAL_SERVICE</resultMsg></header><body><dataType>XML</dataType><items><item><baseDate>20200320</baseDate><baseTime>1500</baseTime><category>PTY</category><nx>60</nx><ny>127</ny><obsrValue>0</obsrValue></item><item><baseDate>20200320</baseDate><baseTime>1500</baseTime><category>REH</category>...

Comment: Show the class `WeatherModel`. It looks like the 2nd line in your xml string doesn't matches with the class.

Comment: Thank you for the WeatherModel class and it worked out